# Swig C++ python wrapper files explanation?

Tags: python, c++, wrapper, swig

I have wrapped a C++ app to python with swig and VS2017 and it works.

I'm not sure which of the output files are needed if I want to use the module else where. I copied `example.py` and `_example.pyd` into another folder and it works there, but I'm not sure if it's general case.

Below are the list of output files? Anyone understand what are each of them for?

```
06/13/2017  13:46             3,617 example.log
06/13/2017  13:45             5,727 example.py
06/13/2017  13:46             8,473 example.pyc
06/13/2017  13:46    <DIR>          example.tlog
06/13/2017  13:46           423,546 example_wrap.obj
06/13/2017  13:46         2,158,592 vc141.pdb
06/13/2017  13:45             2,128 _example.Build.CppClean.log
06/13/2017  13:46               750 _example.exp
06/13/2017  13:46             1,748 _example.lib
06/13/2017  13:46         4,280,320 _example.pdb
06/13/2017  13:46            53,248 _example.pyd
```

Answer (score 1):

Most are intermediate files you won't need.  The `.py` and `.pyd` are the files you need, plus the `_example.pdb` if you use a symbolic debugger to debug `_example.pyd` (really a renamed DLL).